# What's the result when a Readied Action is triggered by another Readied Action?

Tags: dnd-4e, readied-action

Suppose two PCs both ready actions, and the triggering conditions are such that one PC's readied action is triggered by the second PC's readied action.

What's the resulting initiative order if the higher-initiative PC triggers first, and the readied action triggers the lower-initiative PC?

What's the resulting initiative order if the lower-initiative PC triggers first, which then triggers the higher-initiative PC?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In both cases, the PC whose action triggered last goes before the one whose action triggered first.

See [Ready an Action](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=332) (*Player's Handbook* page 291), in particular:

> **Reset Initiative:** After you resolve your readied action, move your place in the initiative order to directly before the creature or the event that triggered your readied action.

Comment: So the math would go something like PCa, PCb, Target.  PCa readies for Target.  PCb redies for PCa to act.  Target makes the action that PCa readied for.  PCb's action then triggers.  Initiative would move around so that it would read PCb -> PCa -> Target, and the actions that each of them have resolve in that order as well.  PCb gets is action, PCa gets to continue his action, then Target gets to finish his action.

Comment: Correct! That's the break-down of the multiple initiative reset.

Comment: And it doesn't matter whether PCa or PCb originally had higher initiative.