# What happens if I provoke reactions from multiple creatures, but the first reaction would prevent me from continuing to provoke those reactions?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack, reactions

Let us picture this scenario: I am standing next to two enemies, and attempt to move directly away from them both, meaning I leave a space in the reach of both. Both of them really want to hit me with their reaction attacks. The first one swings at me, and connects. Unfortunately (for somebody), that enemy also has the [Sentinel](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/sentinel) feat (PHB, p. 169), which means:

> When you hit a creature with an opportunity attack, the creature's speed becomes 0 for the rest of the turn.

I was just hit with an opportunity attack, and thus cannot move, so do I even give the other creature a chance for a reaction attack?

(This is of course just one example of such a situation; another is an opportunity attack which grapples me or drops me prone with insufficient movement left, leaving me unable to move.)

Comment: Have you moved outside the range of the second creature when your speed becomes zero?

Comment: Can you put up a diagram of positioning? I think that'll help us understand the situation.

Comment: @VLAZ I am moving outside the range of both creatures at the same time - imagine they're north and northeast of me, and I move south.

Comment: Is this question about opportunity attacks specifically, or about any reaction in general?

Comment: Re: "The first one swings at me, and connects".  If the first one has Sentinel, and the second does not, does the order of resolution matter?  Who / what is deciding which reaction takes place first?

Comment: Note that in 5e, creatures don’t “threaten spaces”, and opportunity attacks aren’t triggered by leaving such spaces. What matters is leaving the reach of an opponent.

Comment: This is why Magic needs al those complex rules about the stack.

Answer (score 25):

The rules on [opportunity attacks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#OpportunityAttacks) state (emphasis mine):

> To make the opportunity attack, you use your reaction to make one melee attack against the provoking creature. The attack occurs **right before the creature leaves your reach**.

It is up to the DM to adjudicate situations like this, as 5e does not have order of events or interruptions. Ultimately, however, as long as the creature is leaving both opponents' reach by exiting the same space, the fact that they can't actually make it out of the space should not change that both opportunity attacks occur, as they occur "right before" the creature actually leaves the square within reach.

(If instead the creature would first exit one opponent's reach, and then later exit another opponent's reach via a different space, then being prevented from leaving the first space would prevent the second opportunity attack from taking place, since the trigger for it never occurs.)

Comment: *Xanathar's Guide* does have a "Simultaneous Effects" rule, but it makes a mess of this situation, rather than helping.

Comment: The sentence structure in this answer was a bit hard to follow... I've made an edit to try and clarify it a bit. Feel free to edit/improve it further as needed.

Comment: If the action is triggered "right before" an event, but the event never happens, it's not really "right before" the event anymore, is it? Who knew opportunity attacks were in superposition? Sentinel breaks causality!

Comment: @MichaelW. unfortunately for causality breaking fans, the sequence of events is more like 'person turns and runs', 'person they are fighting goes to hit them from behind', 'person they are fighting hits them from behind in such a way they are forced to spin around and defend themselves to avoid being skewered', so the back-turning and fleeing still happens, it just doesn't get very far.

Comment: @user2754 They are definitely not avoiding being skewered when being stopped by a Sentinel. They are very much skewered.

Comment: @user2754 Ah yes, the "turns and runs" trope. It's "D&D: 'Ignoring How Things Actually Work (c)' since 1974."

Answer (score 22):

### Both triggers happened. Both attacks can happen.

If you leave two character's range at the same time, the trigger for the opportunity attack's reaction has happened for both of those characters. As long as nothing inherently prevents the second attack from taking place, such as the target of the attack becoming an invalid target for a melee attack, the trigger was triggered, so the second attack can take place as soon as the first one has been resolved.

Some examples of the target becoming "invalid" can be the target being pushed/teleported outside of the second attacker's melee range, or the target being killed. Do note that the target simply being reduced to 0 hp does not make it an invalid target, and the second attack will still be able to force a failed death save.

Comment: While I'm inclined to agree, I'm curious if there's anything to support this point of view.

Comment: @vonBoomslang I'm myself curious to see if there's anything that supports the opposite. By that, I mean I'm looking for some rule text that would imply that a reaction trigger can be invalidated somehow after it has been triggered already.

Comment: @Matthieu The only thing that comes in mind is some ruling about the interaction of features involving being hit and the *Shield* spell.

Comment: The rule you are looking for is that the DM describes the outcome. Player declares they will move, other players shout opportunity attack, sentinel kicks in, DM declares the character can't move. Doesn't matter how many people shouted opportunity attack, the DM describes the character never moved. The declared opportunity attacks, based on a declared statement of what would happen clash with what actually happens. Now if  the sentinel went last you have an odd situation, but that's why a DM has a brain, or at least one benefit of it.

Comment: @SeriousBri to trigger the effect of Sentinel and stop the character from moving, you need to trigger the opportunity attack. If Sentinel stopped the character from initiating such a trigger, Sentinel couldn't trigger itself in reaction to the movement attempt. In other words, since both the regular and the sentinel opportunity attacks depend on the same trigger, you can't remove the trigger while keeping only one of the two, except if they specify otherwise. This "otherwise" is what I'm looking for, since the trigger isn't "moving out of range" but rather "attempting to move out of range".

Comment: I feel like this has to be the answer. Otherwise the outcome would depend on the arbitrary order in which the opportunity attacks are taken, which makes no sense, as there is nothing specifying the order.

Comment: I thought that reactions happened in initiative order - though can't remember exactly where I get that from (prepared actions maybe?) if anyone has the time to check might be useful?

Comment: @Rycochet you might be getting confused by [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51048/77044) which treats about how 3.5e handles prepared actions. At least that's all I could find regarding potentially using initiative for reactions.

Comment: @Matthieu Definitely not from 3.5 - think it might just have been me as a developer doing a FIFO from multiple people using the same trigger on it - there's definitely nothing in the Ready text to imply it so may not be official at all!

Comment: @Matthieu what you are doing though is rules lawyering this answer. Yes the trigger happens, but that is why the DM exists, to put their brain between A and B. This is a rules paradox, something has to give. You can either make the rules king, or the narrative king, but rules should never be king and the books admit as much.

Comment: @SeriousBri isn't the point of the question to tell what would happen according to the rules? If it wasn't, then the answer would either be subjective or the simple "It's up to the DM". The rules paradox is here to illustrate a logical explanation of the solution, as an answer to your own logical interpretation. But in the end, it only serves to illustrate the interpretation of the rules I present in my answer.

Comment: My point being : if interpreting the rules as they are written isn't the "right" answer for a question that asks how mechanics interact with each others, then the only valid, objective answer is "It's up to the DM", which, in my honest opinion, is both boring and pointless. If you wish to discuss this more in depths, I'll gladly bring this conversation to a chat.